# Circle svg how to add box shadow with css

Tags: html, css

Hi there can someone help me with this circle element on html I need to add a box shadow, but It doesnt work

```css
.circle-chart__circle {
  animation: circle-chart-fill 2s reverse; /* 1 */ 
  transform: rotate(-90deg); /* 2, 3 */
  transform-origin: center; /* 4 */
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(81, 136, 255, 0.2);
}


.circle-chart__info {
  animation: circle-chart-appear 2s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0.3em);
}

@keyframes circle-chart-fill {
  to { stroke-dasharray: 0 100; }
}

@keyframes circle-chart-appear {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

/* Layout styles only, not needed for functionality */
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}

@media (min-width: 31em) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <section>
    <h2>Positive chart value</h2>
    <svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle class="circle-chart__background" stroke="#efefef" stroke-width="2" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
      <circle class="circle-chart__circle" stroke="#00acc1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="30,100" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" cx="16.91549431" cy="16.91549431" r="15.91549431" />
      <g class="circle-chart__info">
        <text class="circle-chart__percent" x="16.91549431" y="15.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="8">30%</text>
        <text class="circle-chart__subline" x="16.91549431" y="20.5" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" font-size="2">Yay 30% progress!</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </section>

</div>
```

I have tried adding the box shadow but it doesn't work can someone help me with this please I am new on coding, is there any hack for this types like

Comment: hello, https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_feoffset.asp this might help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the box shadow property to the circle-chart class itself. It should work! Also, correct your values. Box shadow accepts four values: X position, Y position, blur and colour. You have that second "0" before the rgb that should be gone.